# OAuth Google Calendar

Tags: oauth, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to setup a web interaction with Google calendar I can't seem to get past the OAuth for Javascript. I don't understand how to implement it. Any help would be appreciated.

My big question:
What do I code for the html page with an embedded calendar to show the user's calendar and allow the interaction of adding events through input tags?

Answer (score 1):

-if you know java you can look at [signpost oauth library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) . they have a Google oauth java example at this link page (at the bottom).

-if you prefer javascript try http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/

-there is also a [GWT oauth library](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/)